# Custom user registration form on my WordPress website not passing data to my database

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the tutor lms plugin and the student registration form is not working and requires organization id and orgnaization name but I am not sure why it requires it. I checked the code and there are no fields for it either. [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sakCU.png)

So I decided to try to create my own student registration form and I copied some code from wp-admin/user-new.php file and added it to a new php file to register users into my database. [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIewh.png)

However, when I test it, the data does not get passed into my database. When I check console, no error shoes.

Can anyone give me a lead? Thanks

```
<p><?php _e( 'Create a brand new user and add them to this site.' ); ?></p>

<form method="post" id="createuser" class="validate" novalidate="novalidate"
    <?php
    /** This action is documented in wp-admin/user-new.php */
    do_action( 'user_new_form_tag' );
    ?>
>
<input name="action" type="hidden" value="createuser" />
    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'create-user', '_wpnonce_create-user' ); ?>
    <?php
    // Load up the passed data, else set to a default.
    $creating = isset( $_POST['createuser'] );

    $new_user_login             = $creating && isset( $_POST['user_login'] ) ? wp_unslash( $_POST['user_login'] ) : '';
    $new_user_firstname         = $creating && isset( $_POST['first_name'] ) ? wp_unslash( $_POST['first_name'] ) : '';
    $new_user_lastname          = $creating && isset( $_POST['last_name'] ) ? wp_unslash( $_POST['last_name'] ) : '';
    $new_user_email             = $creating && isset( $_POST['email'] ) ? wp_unslash( $_POST['email'] ) : '';
    $new_user_uri               = $creating && isset( $_POST['url'] ) ? wp_unslash( $_POST['url'] ) : '';
    $new_user_role              = $creating && isset( $_POST['role'] ) ? wp_unslash( $_POST['role'] ) : '';
    $new_user_ignore_pass       = $creating && isset( $_POST['noconfirmation'] ) ? wp_unslash( $_POST['noconfirmation'] ) : '';

    ?>
<table class="form-table" role="presentation">
    <tr class="form-field form-required">
        <th scope="row"><label for="user_login"><?php _e( 'Username' ); ?> <span class="description"><?php _e( '(required)' ); ?></span></label></th>
        <td><input name="user_login" type="text" id="user_login" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $new_user_login ); ?>" aria-required="true" autocapitalize="none" autocorrect="off" maxlength="60" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="form-field form-required">
        <th scope="row"><label for="email"><?php _e( 'Email' ); ?> <span class="description"><?php _e( '(required)' ); ?></span></label></th>
        <td><input name="email" type="email" id="email" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $new_user_email ); ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="form-field">
        <th scope="row"><label for="first_name"><?php _e( 'First Name' ); ?> </label></th>
        <td><input name="first_name" type="text" id="first_name" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $new_user_firstname ); ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="form-field">
        <th scope="row"><label for="last_name"><?php _e( 'Last Name' ); ?> </label></th>
        <td><input name="last_name" type="text" id="last_name" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $new_user_lastname ); ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="form-field">
        <th scope="row"><label for="url"><?php _e( 'Website' ); ?></label></th>
        <td><input name="url" type="url" id="url" class="code" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $new_user_uri ); ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="form-field form-required user-pass1-wrap">
        <th scope="row">
            <label for="pass1">
                <?php _e( 'Password' ); ?>
                <span class="description hide-if-js"><?php _e( '(required)' ); ?></span>
            </label>
        </th>
        <td>
            <input class="hidden" value=" " /><!-- #24364 workaround -->
            <button type="button" class="button wp-generate-pw hide-if-no-js"><?php _e( 'Generate password' ); ?></button>
            <div class="wp-pwd">
                <?php $initial_password = wp_generate_password( 24 ); ?>
                <span class="password-input-wrapper">
                    <input type="password" name="pass1" id="pass1" class="regular-text" autocomplete="off" data-reveal="1" data-pw="<?php echo esc_attr( $initial_password ); ?>" aria-describedby="pass-strength-result" />
                </span>
                <button type="button" class="button wp-hide-pw hide-if-no-js" data-toggle="0" aria-label="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Hide password' ); ?>">
                    <span class="dashicons dashicons-hidden" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="text"><?php _e( 'Hide' ); ?></span>
                </button>
                <div style="display:none" id="pass-strength-result" aria-live="polite"></div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="form-field form-required user-pass2-wrap hide-if-js">
        <th scope="row"><label for="pass2"><?php _e( 'Repeat Password' ); ?> <span class="description"><?php _e( '(required)' ); ?></span></label></th>
        <td>
        <input name="pass2" type="password" id="pass2" autocomplete="off" aria-describedby="pass2-desc" />
        <p class="description" id="pass2-desc"><?php _e( 'Type the password again.' ); ?></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="pw-weak">
        <th><?php _e( 'Confirm Password' ); ?></th>
        <td>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="pw_weak" class="pw-checkbox" />
                <?php _e( 'Confirm use of weak password' ); ?>
            </label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row"><?php _e( 'Send User Notification' ); ?></th>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="send_user_notification" id="send_user_notification" value="1" <?php checked( $new_user_send_notification ); ?> />
            <label for="send_user_notification"><?php _e( 'Send the new user an email about their account.' ); ?></label>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

    <?php
    /** This action is documented in wp-admin/user-new.php */
    do_action( 'user_new_form', 'add-new-user' );
    ?>

    
    <?php submit_button( __( 'Add New User' ), 'primary', 'createuser', true, array( 'id' => 'createusersub' ) ); ?>

</form>
```